# Rocksclusters reinstalling nodes partitioning error

Tags: centos, partition, hpc

I have a HPC based on [rocksclusters](http://www.rocksclusters.org)
So when I've added new roll (torque) I send a kickstart command to all nodes to reinstall them. But after loading X installer on nodes all of them showed me an error:

Could not allocate requested partitions: Partitioning failed: Could not allocate partitions as primary partitions. Cannot allocate partition for /boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the Torque roll, but when adding packages to the compute nodes, if extend-compute.xml doesn't parse correctly, the installation fails because it doesn't do any partitioning. Once you know this, it's of course straightforward to use 'xmllint' to check the xml file before rebuilding the distro, but it took a bit of head-scratching before I figured it out.

So based on that, I would guess there is either a bug in the Torque roll itself, or then you somehow messed up the roll installation.